# How can i get logged user details (image url ,username , email , etc.) with Twitter Kit in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-oauth

How can i get email id , user name and image url from my twitter account after login ,

current code is:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^ (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error)
 {

     if (session)
     {
         NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }

 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be help following code for get `profImage` and `emailId`.

```
TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    // play with Twitter session
    if (session) {
        NSLog(@"Twitter signed in as -> name = %@ id = %@ ", [session userName],[session userID]);

        /* Get user info */
        [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] loadUserWithID:[session userID]
                                                  completion:^(TWTRUser *user,
                                                               NSError *error)
         {
             // handle the response or error
             if (![error isEqual:nil]) {
                 NSLog(@"Twitter info   -> user = %@ ",user);
                 NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:user.profileImageLargeURL];
                 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
                 NSData *pullTwitterPP = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

                 UIImage *profImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pullTwitterPP];


             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Twitter error getting profile : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
             }
         }];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Twitter error signed in : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];

// Get user email address
-(void)requestUserEmail
{
    if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {

        TWTRShareEmailViewController *shareEmailViewController =
        [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
         initWithCompletion:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Email %@ | Error: %@", email, error);
         }];

        [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
    } else {
        // Handle user not signed in (e.g. attempt to log in or show an alert)
    }
}
```